# Set pull to refresh as refreshing on start or resume fragment

Tags: android

I am using this library Android-PullToRefresh: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

I need to implement automatic 'pull to refresh' on activity start, that is having the same visual and functional effect as pulling down the fragment just triggered automatically instead of user pull gestures. Do you know if I can do this ?

EDIT:
My code is as below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frg_summarized, group, false);
    mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.summary_layout);
    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())
    .allChildrenArePullable()
    .listener(this)
    .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);   

    return view;

}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //some code here

    mPullToRefreshLayout.isRefreshing();

}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    if (mPullToRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
     mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    } 

}


@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    if (mPullToRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
        mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Similar to having the ability to call `onRefreshComplete()`, there is a `setRefreshing()` method:

```
myRefreshableView.setRefreshing();
```

Edit:

It looks like `onRefreshStarted` is called [when a user-initiated refresh is started](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/uk/co/senab/actionbarpulltorefresh/library/listeners/OnRefreshListener.java). This means if you want to initiate your own refresh from code, you have to update the UI and start the refresh yourself. I don't see your code for starting the download, but you'd have to pull the contents of that method out to another method, something like this:

```
@Override
public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {
    startDownload();
}
```

Then, when you want to start a download in code (for example in `onResume`):

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    startDownload();
}
```

Your call to `isRefreshing()` in `onActivityCreated` does nothing - that's a check to confirm whether the UI is currently in 'refreshing' state or not. Additionally, you're using that check in your current `onResume` code to perform a call that doesn't actually do anything - if the layout is refreshing, you set it to be refreshing.

Comment: Also, are you aware of the [replacement library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh)? It matches the Pull-To-Refresh behaviour in Gmail and Google+ apps, and works well with the ActionBar.

Comment: I have replaced the Pull to refresh with the one you suggested and all is working fine,However I still can not achive initial refresh on start of the fragmant using the method call someRefreshableView.setRefreshing();

Comment: I've [just implemented this](https://github.com/adamsp/WhatsShaking/commit/408e8dccf5ecfe958dc689904d62e513e218077b#diff-efb9421d4ffa38e80cde340c80b35b7cR183), and I _do_ get the same visual effect - specifically, I get the bars moving across the screen. The "loading" view appears briefly as well. Were you looking for something else, or are you not getting this behaviour? Perhaps you could add some code to the question.

Comment: after correcting like you adviced based on the link  you offered...the  Loading view appears however its simply that,a loading view,its not actualy doing ant of the loading as dictated on my onRefreshStarted(View view). I can only get it to refresh (and run onRefreshStarted(View view) ) on pulling down ...what am I not doing?

Comment: You need to move your download etc code out of `onRefreshStarted` so you can call it yourself from your `onResume`, _as well as_ from `onRefreshStarted`. See updated answer.