# Chris Banes ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

Im using Chris Banes ActionBar-PullToRefresh.
I can start refreshing by pulling the layout down - everything is fine.

But how can i programmatically force start refreshing animation (progress animation)? Or how can i force start full refreshing programmatically like if i pull the layout down?

Tried:

```
mPullToRefreshLayout.startLayoutAnimation();
mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
mPullToRefreshLayout.setActivated(true);
```

Nothing worked.

The only thing i got to work is check for `isRefreshing` and stop it:

```
if(mPullToRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
   mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
}
```

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set pull to refresh as refreshing on start or resume fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006851/set-pull-to-refresh-as-refreshing-on-start-or-resume-fragment)

Comment: `setRefreshing(true)` should start the view animating, but _won't_ call the `onRefreshStarted` callback, you have to call that yourself when you start the refresh animation manually.

Comment: Nop. setRefreshing(true) doesn't work as i said in topic :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually `mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` is working (if `getWindow().getWindowToken != null`). If that's not working , you can see my fork https://github.com/quxey/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Edited . Try this

```
final ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup)getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
                    if(decorView.getWindowToken() == null){
                    decorView.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (decorView.getWindowToken() != null) {
                                        mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                    } else {
                                        decorView.post(this);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    }else{
                    mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                    }
```

Comment: I know that should work, but it doesn't. Seems something is wrong in my app, as temporary measure i've done a progress bar on initial refresh like in GMail. Will look into it in future to fix:)

Answer (score 0):

I briefly looked through the library code and find out where could be problem with listener.

```
    if (fromTouch) {
        if (mOnRefreshListener != null) {
            mOnRefreshListener.onRefreshStarted(view);
        }
    }
```

This part of code from a method `startRefresh(View view, boolean fromTouch)`. Param `fromTouch` points who was refresh initiator. If you start your pulltorefresh without any touch, fromTouch is set `false` so `mOnRefreshListener.onRefreshStarted(view);` is not triggered. I conclude that the method is called only on pull touches. You can check this by yourself maybe your problem was the same.

Answer (score 0):

@AdamS made it simple [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21007107/4183465). A one liner `myRefreshableView.setRefreshing();` I placed it in my fragment's `onResume()`. Works except that since I'm doing this programmatically, I would love to have the refresh **without the pull-to-refresh bounce**.