# Call Chris Banes pull to refresh programmatically without the bounce

Tags: android, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

I'm calling pull-to-refresh programmatically as wonderfully explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21007107/4183465) in a one liner in my fragment's `onResume()`. This is my code:

```
private PullToRefreshScrollView panelScrollView;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    panelScrollView.setRefreshing();            
    super.onResume();
}
```

This refreshes my fragment, but with a **bounce** (as if the user pulled and released) which gives a bad user experience.
My Questions:

1. Can I get the same refresh **without the bounce**?
2. Why isn't the fragment's `super.onResume()` refreshing the fragment once it gets to the foreground? Why do I need to call `PullToRefreshScrollView.setRefreshing()` on the first place?

Comment: Pull to Refresh is natively supported. You don't need third party libraries for this. [See this](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html)

Comment: Use SwipeRefreshLayout Senti.

Comment: Thanks for this!  But this is "legacy code" integrated with a 3rd party pull-to-refresh, which works and I would first like to try without the effort of integrating with another pull-to-refresh solution.  
Also I still don't understand my question 2, why `onResume()` doesn't refresh the fragment without my explicit call.

Comment: As mentioned below in the answer, pull to refresh mechanism is not intended for this. But in case you want it to update whenever you come back in the fragment see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest to use the support pull to refresh very easy to use. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

1. The docs say the following

   > if an activity wishes to show just the progress animation, it should
   >   call setRefreshing(true) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#isRefreshing()
2. The purpose of pull to refresh is that the user specifically want the data to be refreshed. What you are trying to do is kind of an anti pattern. But in ideal situation if you implement pull to refresh you do not want to reload until the user fulfills the action. This way the user can decide on mobile data not to refresh but when connected to wifi quickly refresh.

As an addition to implement refresh when the fragment onResume is called you can create a new class that extends from Fragment.

```
public class AutoRefreshFragment extends Fragment {
 ...
    public void onResume() {
          panelScrollView.setRefreshing();
    }
 ...
}
```

and instead of extends regular Fragment use your superclass `extends AutoRefreshFragment` you just created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!. Please see my comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but this is what I've done in my original code snippet. Or is there a difference I am missing?

Comment: Indeed similar but without the superclass.